# In flutter, which is more secure using platform functions/ dependency or dart dependency?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, security, mobile-security

Im building a mobile application with flutter which the **security is the highest priority** so what is more secure to use native code (functions/ dependency ) or user the dart code/ dependency ?

In other words if I have function OR called **x()** in native **kotlin/java** or **swift** and I have the same thing in dart which of them is more secure to use and **WHY**?

Comment: Sorry but your question is too general so the only possible answer is: It depends on the function and the libraries you want to compare. Making an app insecure is always possible no matter what language you use.

Comment: like for example i want to create crypto suit helper class to handle all blockchain transactions its better to build it in native code or in dart code